# How does mana adders plus mana doublers interact?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This question is related to [How do multiple mana increasers stack?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/42851/how-do-multiple-mana-increasers-stack)

If you have a [Dictate of Karametra](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dictate%20of%20Karametra), a [Zhur-Taa Ancient](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zhur-Taa%20Ancient) and a [Nyxbloom Ancient](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nyxbloom%20Ancient), how much mana gets produced when you tap a [Birds of Paradise](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Birds%20of%20Paradise)?

Is it (1 * 3) + 1 + 1 = 5, or is it, (1 + 1 + 1) * 3 = 9?

Comment: This situation is covered in the last paragraph of [Gendolkari's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/42855/12315).

Comment: zhur-taa and dicatete of karametra only trigger when you tap a land for mana: tapping birds gets you 3 mana from nyxbloom ancient.